# How to get all the keys from dynamic JSON object using pandas in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, rest, web-services

I get a complex JSON response from multiple webservice. I need to get all the keys in various level using python. To use JSON_NORMALISE i need to know the key name. Since i get multiple responses i am not able to give the key name. If i normalize in outer level the json in lower level is not converted into dictionary. It is still in json format.

```
{'Id': 123,
 'oldnumber': 1,
 'new number': 8,
 'version': 1,
 'newversion': 1,
 'personList':[{
         'id':1,
         'name': xyz,
         'marks':[{'phy':90,
                   'che':80
                 }
                {'bot':90,
                   'zoo':80
                 },
                 {'phy':60,
                   'che':80
                 }
                {'bot':20,
                   'zoo':80
                 }
                 ]}
         ],
'anotherList':[{
         'id':1,
         'data': xyz,
         'some':[{'not':90,
                   'dot':80
                 }
                {'cot':90,
                   'pot':80
                 },
                 {'ans':60,
                   'dog':80
                 }
                {'cat':20,
                   'mat':80
                 }
                 ]}
         ]
         }
```

How to read all the key names from the JSON i get from response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the keys from complex JSON object we can directly iterate through the JSON object with simple python. I got the solution from below link.

Reference - https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10

I modified the code a bit and now i am able to get all the keys from JSON

def normalise_json(y):
out = set()

```
def normalise(x):
    if type(x) is dict:
        for a in x:
            out.add(a)
            normalise(x[a])
    elif type(x) is list:
        for a in x:
            normalise(a)

normalise(y)
return out
```